# First php script - no output

Tags: php

I work with WAMP server 2.2.17 and PHP 5.3.5. I'm trying to make a PHP script in ConTEXT (text editor). 
I type literally this:

```
<? php
"hi everyone";
?>
```

And save this with `Save as...` and give the
file name: `"test.php"` (I put `"` that to be sure that he would not changed my extension to `.txt`)
Save as type: All files (and I try with PHP).
I went to WAMP, refresh him and nothing. I type in root location `http://localhost:8080/test.php`
and nothing happens. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Or what else I should do?

Answer (score 6):

It is not valid code. try

```
<?php
echo "hi everyone";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the source code of a page (press Ctrl+U or right-click in most modern browsers), and you'll see the php code.

This means php did not interpret your code. One reason could be that php just echoes everything not in `<?php ... ?>`, and can, unlike a human, not recognize your similar `<? php` (**note the space character**). Another one could be a misconfiguration of php or Apache, most likely missing (`AddType x-httpd-php .php` or php's configuration).

Answer (score 0):

You just created a string variable. You will need to send this to the browsers somehow.

In PHP this can be done with [echo](http://php.net/function.echo), which sends output to the users browser.

So for example:

```
$vartest = 'Hello ';
echo $vartest;
echo "World!";
```

Would send "Hello World!" to the page when you visit it with your browser.

But this assumes you get a blank screen and not a error screen that complains about not finding the website. If this is the case you should check your server.

Also, PHP code bloack starts with either a `<?php` or for short `<?` and ends with a `?>`. Your code would be between these two.